# How to control 3D object's position(or rotation) according to some variables in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scenekit

I have tried to find the solution about this question. But I didn't find the answer yet.(Or it's not appropriate to reach my requirement with SceneKit)

My requirement is that I want to control the position or rotation of 3D object(.dae file) by particular variables in Xcode.

I used the example game file in Xcode 6 to do this.

But the SCNAction fucntion can't use variables as the input parameter.

Example:

```
var position_x = 0.5

var position_y = 3 

var position_z = 4 

SCNAction.moveByX(x, y: position_y, z: position_z, duration: 1.0) // Error
```

I didn't understand why SCNAction can't use variables declared outside?

Or does it have any method to control the position or rotation of object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's the exact error?
`SCNAction` expects `CGFloat` arguments. Does explicitly typing your variables help?

```
var position_x = CGFloat(0.5)
var position_y = CGFloat(3)
var position_z = CGFloat(4)
SCNAction.moveByX(x, y: position_y, z: position_z, duration: 1.0)
```

Comment: Yes, the parameters must be CGFloat type. Thanks a lot!